# AWS Creation Policy for Auto Scaling Group with Mixed Instances Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-auto-scaling

I'm trying to migrate from Auto Scaling Group with constant instance type (f.e. с5.large) to the one which uses 'Mixed instances policy'. Mixed policy I'd like to use will have multiple overrides with different weighted capacity, like this:

```
Overrides:
- InstanceType: c5.18xlarge
  WeightedCapacity: '18'
- InstanceType: c5.24xlarge
  WeightedCapacity: '24'
- InstanceType: c5.2xlarge
  WeightedCapacity: '2'
- InstanceType: c5.4xlarge
  WeightedCapacity: '4'
```

I have other AWS resources which depend on ASG, and I used creation policy on ASG so that CloudFormation will wait until all instances have sent signals and only then ASG will move to 'completed' state allowing to continue deployment of dependent resources.

Now when I switched to Mixed Instance Policy - I cannot know for sure how many instances there will be to satisfy my capacity requirements, so I cannot anymore set creation policy based on signals like this:

```
  "CreationPolicy": {
    "ResourceSignal": {
      "Count": "3",
      "Timeout": "PT15M"
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to have reliable 'waiting' logic in CloudFormation template for Auto Scaling Group which uses Mixed Instance Policy?

Answer (score 1):

Mixed instances policy is a way to specify which type of instances to create, combining on-demand and spot instances. More information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/APIReference/API_MixedInstancesPolicy.html).

The *CreationPolicy* key is related to the AutoScalingGroup so you can continue to use it by specifing it in the CloudFormation configuration.

Regarding the unreliable instance number, it's possible to tune the *MixedInstancesPolicy* in a doublefold way.
Setting the desired instance number:

```
"MinSize": 1,
"MaxSize": 5,
"DesiredCapacity": 3,
```

InstancesDistribution parameters to specify the distribution of on-demand instances and spot instances and the allocation strategies used to fulfill them, such as:

```
"InstancesDistribution": {
   "OnDemandBaseCapacity": 1,
   "OnDemandPercentageAboveBaseCapacity": 0,
   "SpotAllocationStrategy": "capacity-optimized"
}
```

Comment: Alez, thank you for response, unfortunately if I leave creation policy and delete signals count leaving only timeout, I see undesired behavior - from ec2 instances logs I see that according to timestamps - ec2 instance is not ready yet, but ASG already has completed state, thus I have issues in dependent services. I need to wait for Capacity to be available. Creation policy seems to deal with signals from ec2 instances not taking capacity into account, or I'm not right?

Comment: Hi XZen, probably your issue is related to the scaling policy that could consider a scaling activity soon after the instance is created but your applications require some time to initialize. 
I suggest you to try adding lifecycle hooks to ASG to control when instances are registered with ELB, the bootstrap scripts have completed and the applications are ready to accept traffic. Additionally, you can add warmup instances to ASG to decrease the time to initialize your application before starting to serve traffic.

Comment: Hi Alez, from logs I see that there's enough time for ec2 instances to send signals, it's just  that as I understand ASG creation policy expects particular number of signals and doesn't seem to take into account that there're different weights of instances and there should be different 'contribution'. I'm using `Signals.waitForMinCapacity...` L2 java code in AutoScalingGroup object constructor and don't set any numbers, only timeout. Still I see that 5 instances sent signals, but capacity = 10 and it waits for another 5 signals. If only there was a way in signal to specify 'weight' of signal..

Comment: Also, in case I set 0 manually, but using `Signals.waitForCount` instead of `Signals.waitForMinCapacity` - it seems it doesn't wait neither for signals nor for capacity and puts ASG to completed state too early, which breaks future operations :(

Comment: Among the options for Signals.waitForMinCapacity(), there is the [minSuccessPercentage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-autoscaling.SignalsOptions.html#minsuccesspercentage) signal that consider the percentage of signals that need to be successful. Have you tried it?